# How to stop audio in html export?

Tags: godot, gdscript

There was a problem with audio playing in the exported instance of the game. The sound is played using the AudioStreamPlayer node. I export the game to html5 and run it either on a local server or on any service that executes html code. If during the game you minimize the browser, change the tab, make the game window NOT active, then all game processes are suspended, that is: the movement of all objects does not occur, all timers are suspended. BUT the music continues to play. I tried to handle a focus Notification , an input handle with a cursor to turn off the music, but this is not an option, because if you minimize the browser via alt + tab while on the tab with the game, then the focus does not go away and the input is still waiting (while as I said earlier, all other processes related to movement and the timer are suspended).

How stop this audio stream in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
func _notification(what): 

    if what == MainLoop.NOTIFICATION_WM_FOCUS_IN: get_tree().paused = false
    elif what == MainLoop.NOTIFICATION_WM_FOCUS_OUT:get_tree().paused = true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**